# SSAS / MDX Query - Sort a CellSet

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an MDX query where I am returning a list of products and the total sales value for that item from my SSAS cube, like so:

```
 SELECT  
 NON EMPTY   
 { [Item].Children } ON COLUMNS,
 { [Total Line Value] } ON ROWS
 FROM        [Sales Analysis]
```

What I would like to do is sort the results in a descending fashion (ie the part that has sold the most will be at the top, and so forth). Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx)

```
SELECT  
 NON EMPTY   
 Order([Item].Children, Measures.[Total Line Value], DESC) ON COLUMNS,
 { [Total Line Value] } ON ROWS
 FROM        [Sales Analysis]
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. I was trying it like so:

SELECT  
 NON EMPTY   
 { [Item].Children } ON COLUMNS,
 Order({ [Total Line Value] }, DESC) ON ROWS
 FROM        [Sales Analysis]

Comment: Just an extension to this: I wish to add another dimension to my query, whereby I select the total amount for a given month and year. I have this all set up in my cube but I'm not sure on the query needed: SELECT  
                                NON EMPTY   
                                ORDER       ( [Item].Children, Measures.[Total Line Value], DESC),
                                            { [January 2010].Children} ON COLUMNS,
                                            { [Total Line Value] } ON ROWS
                                FROM        [Sales Analysis]